# Unable to open razor page because of @page {id} type

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a link in Index page with the Id is string:

```
 <a href="/usr/view/@Item.Id">Edit</a>
```

When this link is clicked, it suppose to open View page, but it didn't. This is the View page:

```
@page "/usr/view/{id:int}"

<h3>View</h3>

@code {
[Parameter] public int id { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to change the {id:int} to {id:string} but this error came out:

```
Unsupported constraint 'string' in route '/usr/view/{id:string}'.
```

How do I go about this? My Id must be a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just `@page "/usr/view/{id}"`? You might also want to use `asp-page` and `asp-route-id` in the anchor tag, so that you can change the URL without having to change the HTML link.

`string` [is the default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-parameters) if no constraint is provided.